# Accessing mongodb in c9.ide terminal

Tags: mongodb, cloud9-ide

I am working on c9.ide editor where trying to connect mongodb in terminal

I have run command in terminal

I have tried `--bind_ip` by setting `$IP`, `localhost` as well as `0.0.0.0` but nothing worked

`$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=process.env.IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"' > mongod
$ ./mongod`

It displayed message as per below image[image]

Then in another terminal I have run command

`$ mongo`

But its giving me cannot connect message, Let me know what I am doing wrong

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Run this command:

   $ mongod --bind_ip=$IP --nojournal
2. You will see an output of very last line like:

   waiting for connections on port 27017
3. open the mongo shell in a new Terminal, run the following command:

   $ mongo

Hope, this could solve the problem.

Ref: [Set Up a Database in c9.io](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setup-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `process.env.IP` for specifying the value to `--bind_ip` option, but I don't think that'll work.

```
mongod --bind_ip=$IP --dbpath=data --nojournal --rest "$@"
```

should work, and even if that doesn't just try '0.0.0.0', which is the value of $IP

Comment: I have tried that values. Will check again on next working day